# How to reference an equation in latex and line wrap the reference in the text?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, word-wrap, math-mode

I got an equation in my latex document in an align environment. I labeled my equation and I'm referencing this equation in my document.

However, then I'm doing this like this:

```
\begin{align} \label{eq:slopeSaturation}
  <some formula>
\end{align}

<some text> \ref{eq:slopeSaturation} <some more text>
```

I get the problem that the equation is correctly referenced in the text, but the reference is overlapping my margin of the document.

I already tried to use the following properties in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakcites}
```

But this makes no difference for my referenced equations.

Do you have an idea for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using

```
\eqref{eq:slopeSaturation}
```

or

```
\autoref{eq:slopeSaturation}
```

which will create references particularly catering towards equations (or anything really for autoref...)

Comment: thank you, for your answer, but this does also not work.. it just put brackets arround my reference

Comment: autoref did it for me! - Can you explain the difference between ref, eqref and autoref?

Comment: SO guidelines suggest not to answer separate questions (that are not for clarification of specific technical issues related to the original answer) in the comment section. I would advise you to ask a new question or read the related package documentation